# real struggle trying to parse a table

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html5lib

I am trying to parse a table (of prices) from a web and it is turning out a real struggle

here is the web

```
url='http://www.zonebourse.com/AEX-7959/composition/'
```

with bs4:

```
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data,"html5lib")
tables =soup.find('table',id='ALNI4')

print tables
```

with html5lib:

```
df=pd.read_html(url)
print df
```

In both cases no tables found, could anyone help me parse the table or at least understand what is the problem?

```
ValueError: No tables found
```

I would like to discard the option of `xml` if possible, having problems to install so dont use at all.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you get an error of any kind?

Comment: ValueError: No tables found

Comment: Well, when I try visiting the url you posted, I don't get anything back. I did `res= requests.get("http://www.zonebourse.com/AEX-7959/composition/")` and `res.text` returns `''`. Is that the right URL?

Comment: Sorry quotes were needed in the example

Comment: I don't see anything on the page. The page is all empty

Comment: You are right , days ago that link took you to the composition section as you can appreciate under the web header , is there ANYWAY i can get the table over there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are looking for

```
url='http://www.zonebourse.com/AEX-7959/composition%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B/'
```

Comment: Ah shoot! You beat me to it! Well played ;)

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, the URL you are pointing to is wrong. I searched for what the URL actually is, and it is actually `http://www.zonebourse.com/AEX-7959/composition%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B/`.

I do not know why the URL is this weird.

If you make that edit, (`url='http://www.zonebourse.com/AEX-7959/composition%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B/'`) your code should work correctly (though I did not test it myself!)

Hope it helps! Bonne chance!